# infinite loop using mapStruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, recursion, mapstruct, mapper

i have a problem, i have 3 objects:

**object A:** has as attribute a collection of Objetc B

**Object B:** has as attribute a Object A and a collection of Object C

**object C:** has as attribute a Object B and a Collection of Object C

I am using **MapStruct** t do the objects mappers but when i try to mapper this objects, the code enter in infinite loop.

Are there some solution for this problem?

Thanks and sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapstruct bidirectional mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895166/mapstruct-bidirectional-mapping)

Comment: I have try it that solution, but it doens't work for me

Comment: I thinck that the problem is de object C dependency becouse he has a dependency himself

Comment: You need to correctly apply the solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895166/mapstruct-bidirectional-mapping to your objects. This is identical to that one

Comment: I have already tried that solution, but not working for me, using that solution the dependency B en C objects is null, i think that the problem is the objectC dependency himself

Comment: This is a solution that in principle should work. You won't get any more responses without providing some code that could allow someone to reproduce your specific issue.